# I want a reliable textbook to understand (orthogonality- orthonormality - inner product)

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, orthogonality

I want to understand these topics mathematically since I've encountered some of them lately while studying physics ,thank you in advance

Comment: In addition to Strang (mentioned below), another popular and very good textbook is the one by [Fridberg, Insel, and Spence](http://www.amazon.com/Linear-Algebra-Edition-Stephen-Friedberg/dp/0130084514).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gilbert Strang's Linear Algebra and its Applications is a good place to start. Any intro linear algebra book will cover them though.

Comment: I didn't find the inner product there 
like <a,b>

Comment: He mentions that all inner products on finite dimensional vector spaces are of the form $x^T M y$ where $M$ is a positive definite matrix. If you want to see the notation specifically, you can check out something like friedberg, insel and spence's linear algebra which is a bit more advanced.